# Can webspere appserver can be installed and run by an AD account on Linux with no issues while operations?

Tags: websphere

would like to know if I can install and run WebSphere application ND 8.5.5 server on Linux using Active Directory account with no challenges in production operations?

Comment: Probably, but if anything happens to the AD, you would have problems in your WAS as well.  I would **never** do that, since I have had to many problems with AD (changes in the structure, network issues, password expiration, ...).  I always get a specific local user specifically created for WAS.  I make this user unable to login directly.  so I login with my user, than switch user to wasuser.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the authentication model for WAS apps, then I have many customers that do this. To address Nic3500's concern, you should ensure that when connecting WAS to AD, you are using a Federated Repository model. This ensures that if AD is down, you have a backup user you can log in with. A single repository model would use AD only and thus lock you out. A Federated repository allows you to connect to multiple LDAPs and as well as the built in stand alone repository.

As far as Linux goes, that is the gold standard in my book. When you install it, you also want to be sure to setup a systemd unit file so it starts/stop with the operating system.

Now, if you are referring to the operating system user that WAS runs under, then it should be a separate account for optimal security. If your operating system security connects to LDAP, then consult with your AD administrator so you setup a redundant connection. In this case, I would echo Nic3500's concern and ensure the operating system account is local as well.